# Find a character based on position and match everything after in regex and logstash

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

This is my string:

> *msg: Malware/Virus detected -
>   Rtf.Exploit.CVE_2017_11882-6584355-0:Message denied for
>   delivery:Announcement: Holiday Tomorrow*

The string above is a log line. I want to find the 3rd colon and match everything after it. The `Announcement: Holiday Tomorrow` is a subject title so I can have a colon or not.

I tried this so far

```
[^:]+$     // Holiday Tomorrow
(?<=:).*$  //  Malware/Virus detected - Rtf.Exploit.CVE_2017_11882-6584355-0:Message denied for delivery:Announcement: Holiday Tomorrow"
```

I will be using the regex in my logstash config.

```
grok {

    match {
        "msg" => "(regex here)%{GREEDYDATA:subject}"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (but I don't know anything about lagstash):

`(?:.+?:){3}(.*)`  capture group 1 will have what you want

Skip past 3 `.+:`'s and capture the rest.

https://regex101.com/r/p2jodw/3

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping out. actually gave up on regex in logstash

Answer (score 0):

Gave up on regex in logstash for this particular log.
Instead
I modified my log/String to have a "Subject - " part instead. so logstash config can be simple
From this

> msg: Malware/Virus detected - Rtf.Exploit.CVE_2017_11882-6584355-0:Message denied for delivery: Subject - Announcement: Holiday Tomorrow

To this

> msg: Malware/Virus detected - Rtf.Exploit.CVE_2017_11882-6584355-0:Message denied for delivery: Subject - Announcement: Holiday Tomorrow

```
grok {

 match {

 "msg" => "Subject - %{GREEDYDATA:headerSubject}"

 }

}
```